# How to config depth of cascade operation in EclipseLink?

Tags: jpa, jpa-2.0, eclipselink

For example, there is a relationship between A , B and C:

A has Many B, B has many C.

I want to remove B and C while remove A.

Default is, When remove A, B can be removed at the same time, but C can not.